# Write first 10 characters of each line to new file using bash

Tags: bash

I apologize for using code designation with my file contents but the formatting was being weird otherwise.

***I have a 6,6494,940 line file that contains the following:***

```
@MSQ-M01247R:81:000000000-ACWD8:1:1101:11811:1088 2:N:0:
CCCCCTCTTCCCTTTCTTCCCCCCTCTTTCTTCTTTCTCTTTTCTCCCTCTCCTTTTTTTCTCCTTTTTTTCCTTT
+
############################################################################
```

***I want to write the first 10 characters of each line to a new file in order:***

```
@MSQ-M0124
CCCCCTCTTC
+
##########
```

***I used the following bash script:***

```
while read line
do
        long=$line
        short=${long:0:10}
        echo ${short} 
done < $1
```

***With the following command:***

```
./bashscript.sh fileread.fastq >> filewrite.fastq
```

## Results

Something went wrong. My new/write file had 628,429,568 but it should have had 66,494,940 like the original/read file. So it looks like it kept looping.

When I use the head command on the new/write file I get:

```
@MSQ-M0124
CCCCCTCTTC
+
##########
@MSQ-M0124
CCTCCTCCTT
+
##########
@MSQ-M0124
CCTTCTTCTT
```

When I use the tail command I get:

```
CCCCCGGGGG
+
CCCCCGGGGG
GAGTCGTCTG
+
CCCCCGGGGG
+
CCCCCGGGGG
GAGTCGTCTG
+
CCCCCGGGGG
+
CCCCCGGGGG
GAGTCGTCTG
+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cut` is your friend!

```
$ cut -c-10 file
@MSQ-M0124
CCCCCTCTTC
+
##########
```

This uses `cut` with the option `-c`, from **c**haracters, to get the range `-10`, which implicitly means from the 1st to the 10th.

Comment: Thanks!! This worked perfectly and was so much faster to run.